# Why are files in a smbfs mounted share created with executable bit set?

Tags: permissions, cifs

I mounted a samba share using the smbmount command:

```
$ sudo smbmount \\\\foo\\bar /mnt/bar -o user=tom
```

When I create new files, they get created with the executable bit set for owner, group and world. For e.g.

```
$ touch hello.txt 
$ ls -la hello.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Dec  2 12:28 hello.txt
```

The same file when created on a NFS mounted share sets up correct permissions without any executable bit set.

Why is this happening? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

NFS was invented in the Unix world and so understands traditional Unix permissions out of the box. (The ACL of modern unix systems are another matter, but recent implementations of NFS should cope with them.)

Samba was invented in the IBM/Microsoft PC world, to exchange files with systems that had no permissions beyond read-only/read-write. It is now native to Windows. By default, Samba does not transmit Unix permissions. Depending on the configuration, either all files are marked executable (which is annoying) or all files (except directories) are marked non-executable (which is annoying).

There are various extensions to the Samba/CIFS protocol that make it more suited for Unix use. Try enabling [Unix extensions](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#UNIXEXTENSIONS) in the server configuration:

```
[global]
unix extensions = yes
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my company intranet, I don't have access to configure the server. Perhaps, it would be best to mount just using NFS on a Linux client. The bigger problem is on a Windows client, where configuring NFS is a pain in the neck.

Comment: @vivekian2 Indeed, if you have the choice, I definitely recommend using NFS on a Linux client and SMB on a Windows client.

Answer (score 16):

This sounds like your issue: [Copied files gain execute bit on Samba/CIFS](http://jurjenbokma.com/ApprenticesNotes/map_archive_bit_on_samba.xhtml).

*excerpt*

> After copying a file with rw-r----- on a CIFS-mounted volume, the copy gets rwxr-----. So it's gaining the execute bit:

Further down the page, setting `map archive = no` in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

*excerpt*

```
  [Global]
  <snip>
  map archive = no
  <snip>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can find out *why* this is happening from the following explanation on the Samba web site under the **File Permissions and Attributes on MS-DOS and Unix** section:

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html

It has to do with mapping the System, Hidden and Archive bits for an MS-DOS filesystem.

An MS-DOS filesystem doesn't make use of executable bits so the three executable bits on the Unix filesystem are reused to represent the System, Hidden and Archive bits for the MS-DOS filesystem.

So when you view the file permissions using `ls -l` in Unix, you're viewing the file permissions suitable for MS-DOS (or Windows) keeping in mind that the three executable bits in Unix represent the System, Hidden and Archive bits for MS-DOS.

In `smb.conf`, however, you can turn this mapping off for a share with:

```
map archive = no
map system = no
map hidden = no
```

and force the mode on creation of files with:

```
force create mode = 0660
```

Answer (score 8):

You might try: `mount -t cifs`

Google "mount cifs" for usage, it's not hard to understand, but you'll want to set options using the -o flag:

```
uid=<user>,gid=<group>,rw,noperm,dir_mask=0775,file_mask=0664
```

or

```
uid=<user>,gid=<group>,rw,noperm,dir_mode=0775,file_mode=0664
```

User and group are id's, as in numeric not the text alias.  These options will ensure that you have r/w access, permissions are controlled by the mount no the server, and specifically `file_mask=0664` (or `file_mode=0664`) will ensure that your files are not executable.  On top of this you'll be able to work with your samba shares as local directories.

Comment: That is not a solution. The files are still created executable on the server, but you see them as `file_mode` on the client, even if they really are executable on the server.

Answer (score 2):

I use a QNAP TS439 - and had this issue with files being executable.

Although I had to use the following in my `/etc/fstab` file

```
//192.168.0.1/audio /media/audio cifs credentials=/home/cheese/.smbcredentials,uid=1000,file_mode=0664,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```