# How to enable unix file permissions on samba share with smb 2.0+

Tags: mount, samba, cifs, smb

I am trying to set permissions on a Samba share mounted with `vers=3.0`, but it does not work (with `vers=2.1` or `vers=2.0` also issue is present).

As per [SMB3-Linux](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/SMB3-Linux) `cifsacl` option is needed for setting the permission bits, but if that option is used the folder does not mount:

```
# mount -t cifs //server.lan/aaditya /home/roaming/SERVER/aaditya -o 'username=aaditya,domain=server.lan,password=mypass,cifsacl,vers=3.0,nobrl,mfsymlinks,sfu,uid=1274545246,gid=1274544641'
```

> mount error(95): Operation not supported Refer to the mount.cifs(8)
>   manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Is there something that I am missing?

It works with `vers=1.0` which has unix extensions but trying to avoid it as SMB 2.0+ seems to have much better performance and design ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block#History) and [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2008/11/11/file-server-performance-improvements-with-the-smb2-protocol-in-windows-server-2008/)).

Client details:

```
# mount.cifs -V
mount.cifs version: 6.4

# uname -srm
Linux 4.10.0-38-lowlatency x86_64

# lsb_release -ird
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
```

Server details:

```
$ uname -srm
Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64

$ lsb_release -ird
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04

$ samba --version
Version 4.6.7-Ubuntu
```

Comment: I dont know why **mount.cifs** fails with _cifsacl_; tried it on another system running Slackware where it worked. However, it _fails_ to solve the main issue, ie, enabling unix permissions on a SMB 2.0 share.

Anyhow I discovered _why_ all the files were being shown as executable in the share: its due to mapping some windows file permissions as described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103415/why-are-files-in-a-smbfs-mounted-share-created-with-executable-bit-set. Even if `file_mode=0644` is explicitly added, the files become non executbable with no way of setting them otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Samba does not yet support UNIX extensions for SMB v2.0+. It is being worked on. [[lists.samba.org, 10/2017](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2017-October/211517.html)]

They say that when UNIX extensions will be finalized, the Samba implementation is *”not going to allow clients to create ’real‘ symlinks on the server - only SMB-followable symlinks. Allowing clients to create real server symlinks as in SMB1 UNIX extensions has been a long-term security disaster.“* [[same thread](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2017-October/211522.html)]

Comment: Holy moly. In hours of reading samba docs, trying to figure out why file permissions were not appearing correctly on the client side, I didn't find any mention of unix extensions being restricted to SMB1. Thank you.